# Access $_FILE['tmp_name'] from the UploadedFile class?

Tags: image, symfony, upload

if I print the content of an instance of UploadedFile, this is what I get

```
array (
  'opt_image_header' => 
     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
       'test' => false,
       'originalName' => 'triangle-in-the-mountains.jpg',
       'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
       'size' => 463833,
       'error' => 0,
)
```

And this is how I get the uploaded file in the Controller. Before of moving it, I should resize it.

```
  foreach($request->files as $uploadedFile){

      $ext = '.' . $uploadedFile['opt_image_header']->guessExtension();
      $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . $ext;

      $uploadedFile['opt_image_header']->move($path . '/images/', $filename);

  }
```

so there's no the "tmp_name" that I'd need for resizing the image before of saving it.

Do I need to read it directly from the $_FILE array?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Use `$uploadedFile->getRealPath()`

[`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) extends [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html), which extends PHP's [`SplFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php), so `UploadedFile` inherits all methods from `SplFileInfo`.

Use `$uploadedFile->getRealPath()` for the absolute path for the file. You can also use other methods on it, such as `getFilename()` or `getPathname()`. For a complete list of available methods (of `SplFileInfo`), see [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php).

Symfony's File class adds some extra methods, such as `move()` and `getMimeType()`, and adds backward compatibility for `getExtension()` (which was not available before PHP 5.3.6). `UploadedFile` adds some extra methods on top of that, such as `getClientOriginalName()` and `getClientSize()`, which provide the same information as you would normally get from `$_FILES['name']` and `$_FILES['size']`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uploading a file with Doctrine, take a look at [Symfony Documentation Upload a file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)
If you want to upload a file without Doctrine, you can try something like:

```
foreach($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
    $filename = $uploadedFile->get('Put_Input_Name_Here')->getClientOriginalName();
    $file = $uploadedFile->move($distination_path, $filename);
}
```

If there was any issue for uploading file `move()` will throw an exception

**UPDATED**
According to get the temp path of the uploaded file to resize the image you can use `getPath()` function in the mentioned loop

```
$tmp_name = $uploadedFile->get('Put_Input_Name_Here')->getPath();
```

If you ask why, because the Symfony File class is extends [SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/SplFileInfo)

Comment: The upload goes fine, the problem is that I should resize it before of uploading it. I would do that in plain PHP loading the $_FILES['tmp_name'] file and resizing it. I wonder why there's no accessor for that property in UploadedFile

Comment: @Carlo Maybe the easy solution is to resize your image after upload. You know the destination path for your uploaded image so you can apply changes on that. Furthermore, you can define a temp upload path in `config.yml` then you will have the temp path to the uploaded file